# How to set CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAG -L equivalent for MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, linker

On UNIX-like machines, I'm using

```
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -L/some/path")
```

to add `/some/path` to the linker path.

What is the equivalent of the `-L/some/path` for MSVC (Microsoft Visual Studio C++ compiler)? Or, is there any portable way of adding an additional linker path so the linker can find the additional libraries I'm linking against?

Comment: What is wrong with `link_libraries`/`target_link_libraries`? Specifying `-l`/`-L` flags in the `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` are used mostly for *toolchain*, not for the normal libraries.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'm adding some library that is not in the usual path, I just want to make the linker "look" into this custom path (otherwise I'm getting a linker error). So how would you specify the path in the most "cmake"-like way?

Comment: Have you looked into [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library) about linking external library?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks, that was exactly what I needed, I'll mark this question as a dupe